# How to determine the dimensions of a subplot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, subplot

So I am writing a function that plots matrix data from *n* different cells. If *n* is 10, it should display 10 equally spaced plots on a single figure. If **n** is 7, it should try to space them out as equally as possible (so 3x2 or 2x3 plots with a plot by itself).

I am able to get these graphs drawn using `subplot()` and `plot()` but I'm having a hard time finding out how to initialise the dimensions for the subplot.

The number of subplots will be changing after each run so I can't initialise it to specific dimensions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like you have arbitrary rules to determine the number of rows & columns & number of figures based on the number of cells you need to plot (10 cells -> single figure, 7 cells -> 2 figures).  Is it codifying these rules that you are asking for help with or help with actioning the resulting row, column & figure counts?

Comment: Do you have an upper bound for the maximum number of subplots? Is it high? If not, you might want to hard code the different scenarii. If yes, you'll want to get the closest integer from your number of subplots that can be expressed as a product of 2 factors "not too far" from eachother. In your example, 7 is prime so you'll never bee able to equally space tour subplots, so you'll want to express 7 as 3x2+1.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid problems like this tend to be messy. This normally problems like this need to be solved for different cases.

```
if (mod(n,2) && n<8)
    % Do something
elseif (!mod(n,2) && n < 11)
    % Do something else
elseif ...
    ....
end
```

The conditions are choosen a bit arbitarily since the specifications in the OP seemed a bit arbitary too. You probably understand the point and can set your own conditions.

There are two reasons why I recommend this approach.

1) This makes the code simpler to write. You do not have to come up with some complicated solution which may break in after some time.

2) By adding cases you can protect yourself against a rampant number of plots. In case the number of plots gets too large you do typically not want to have all plots in the same figure. It is also possible to wrap this into a function and apply this to X plots at a time in a loop. Typically you would want each iteration to be a separate figure.

It is not very easy to elaborate more on this since you have not yet specified how many cases you expect or what will happen to the last plot in case of odd numbers. Still this may give a good hint.

Good luck!

Comment: In addition with your answer, I think seeking conditions by taking the prime number decomposition of n would help a lot.

Comment: @BillBokeey I assumes that prime number decomposition is meant to be used to determine the size of the subplot, or am I wrong? So to say in case there for example are 9 plots, the subplot can be 3x3?

Comment: Yes exactly, in my mind it would be : find the two factors in the prime numbers decomposition that gives the best heigth:width ratio, if not found, repeat with n-1 and so on. But again, it's just a random thought. For example, if n=12=3x2x2 , 3x4 would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution would be using `round` and `ceil` on the square root:

```
for n=1:20
    [n, round(sqrt(n))*ceil(sqrt(n)),  round(sqrt(n)), ceil(sqrt(n))]
end
```

output:

```
%(n, total_plots, x, y)
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     1     2
 3     4     2     2
 4     4     2     2
 5     6     2     3
 6     6     2     3
 7     9     3     3
 8     9     3     3
 9     9     3     3
10    12     3     4
```

Usage example:

```
n = 7
subplot(round(sqrt(n)), ceil(sqrt(n)), plot_nr_x) % switch first 2 params to have either a slightly longer or slightly wider subplot
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem today and I was having a lot of trouble to define the size of the subplot that would fit everything. My reasoning is mostly a hack but it can help. If you have to represent at most `n` figures, you can thing as a square grid of `sqrt(n) * sqrt(n)`. To make things better we add a safety row, so the final matrix would be `(sqrt(n) + 1) * sqrt(n)`. I hope this helps solving your problem.

In my code have 2 nested loops:

within a loop that opens a figure for each `kk` element and is meant to plot a particular graph from the `x` position within the array.

```
for kk=1:length(some_file_list)

      % Load data
      % do some math
      % get data as a cell array with things we care about in data(3,)

    array_size = size(data(3,:),2);

      for x=1:size(data(3,:),2);

    % do more math and get things ready to plot matrix_A scaled by range_A

            figure(kk); % open figure       
                grid_rows = round((sqrt(array_size)+1));
                grid_cols = round(sqrt(array_size));

                % plot
                subplot(grid_rows, grid_cols, x);
                imagesc(matrix_A,range_A); %plot in position
                colormap(gray);
         end
 end
```